# Mac app call shell script kill self

Tags: macos, shell, kill

I write a mac application. I call a shell script to do some tasks in my mac app. when shell script tasks complete, I want to kill my mac app and reopen it.

I can `pgrep [app_name] | xargs  kill -9` in shell script. but it does not work.

When I execute this command in my terminal it works. How can I kill my mac app in my shell script ? Hope you can help.

Comment: I want to know how to relaunch a mac app in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
/usr/bin/pkill -9 <app name>
```

Failing that, and if the app spawns multiple prcesses:

```
for PID in $(/usr/bin/pgrep <app name>); do /bin/kill -9 $PID; done
```

If the process is running as root, you'll need to run the script as root or with sudo.

If you're still struggling do the following to help you debug:

```
#!/bin/bash

APP='<appname>'
LOG= ~/debugkill.log
PIDS: `/usr/bin/pgrep $APP`

echo -e "`/bin/date`: Script running as user: `/usr/bin/whoami` \n
  Process to be killed owned by: `ps u $APP | /usr/bin/awk { print $1 }'`" >> $LOG

echo -e "PIDs to terminate: $PIDS >> $LOG
echo -e "Killing PIDs..." 
for PID in $PIDS; do
  /bin/kill -9 $PID
  if [[ `ps $PID | grep $PID | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }'` == "$PID" ]]; then
    echo 'killing with sudo (requires pass)'
    sudo /bin/kill -9 $PID
  fi

  if [[ `ps $PID | grep $PID | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }'` == "$PID" ]]; then
    echo 'killing with killall -9'
    /usr/bin/killall -9 $APP
  fi
done >> $LOG
```

I've had issues before with not being killed from scripts and it turned out that the binary paths weren't specified explicitly for either pkill or kill - and because they are in different folders sometimes one works and the other doesn't depending on which environmental variables are at play when running it.

To relaunch your app, you need to be clear on what app it is, whether it's launched by a binary or launched by java or something, and whether any config parameters are specified when you check the process for it whilst running i.e. run 'ps ax ' and see if anything is running 
like so: 
/usr/sbin/xinetd -dontfork -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid

..as when you relaunch you will need to include the same so you'd do something like this in the script:

/usr/sbin/xinetd -dontfork -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid > /dev/null 2>&1

..the other option is to turn the app into a daemon via launchd and then you can simply stop and restart\stop\start the process:
http://blog.frd.mn/how-to-set-up-proper-startstop-services-ubuntu-debian-mac-windows/

Comment: It doesn't work. This command is similar to `pgrep [app_name] | xargs  kill -9`. It only work in terminal.

Comment: Try again with the paths to the binaries properly specified, and try with super user and see if it makes a difference. Make sure you've got #!/bin/bash or #!/usr/bin/env bash at top of the script.

I'll edit the script to show you some useful debugging tips.

Comment: Thank you very much .  `pgrep [name]` get nothing in my script. so I change it to `ps -A | grep [name]' , then I call 'kill -9  $pid'. It works now.